# .NET 4.5: Random "request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" after Windows Update

Tags: .net, ssl, windows-server-2008

My production system is randomly getting the error

`System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`

making webrequests to external systems. Happening 1-5% of the time.

Server is **Windows Server 2008 R2** with .NET 4.5.1 installed. The executable in question is compiled against 4.5.0.

It seems to have started after the server got completely patched on Oct 3rd, which had not been done previously since Dec 2015 (I know).

So wondering if there was something related to a Windows Update patch that affected something?

Here's partial output from openssl command for cert inspection of the destination server:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect XXX:443

SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: [redacted]
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: [redacted]
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1477583093
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
```

And from another URL:

```
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: [redacted]
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: [redacted]
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1477583776
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
    Extended master secret: no
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar issue.

Comment: @dman2306 sorry, no